# Sending data from Multiple form Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Hi I am using Ajax to change certain columns on the database.
Since I have multiple forms on the page, how do I send the data to Ajax?

I used the following code and it does not work:

```
$('form').submit(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() { 
                alert($(this).serialize());
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.success == false)
                {  
                } 
                else 
                {   

                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            }
        });
        return false;
   });
```

The alert always shows nothing, I have given a "name" attribute to each of my inputs. Please help!

Comment: one way would be to add a class to each form, e.g. `<form class="multi-form">` then in the jQuery, `data: $('form.multi-form').serialize(),` then that will combine all the data from the separate forms into one array to send it to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works, but is there a way to get the data only from the form where submit button was clicked?

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` should work, try storing it in a variable before the ajax call, e.g. `var data = $(this).serialize();` then `data: data,`

Comment: Ah yes, apparently storing it in a variable did the trick. Thanks a million!

Comment: No probs, the reason is because once in the ajax function, the context of `$(this)` changes so it wasn't doing what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

It is fixed, apparently all I need to do is to store `$(this).serialize` into a variable first before sending it through Ajax.